# How can I keep a reference to a key after it has been inserted into a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I want to insert into a HashMap but keep an immutable borrow of the key to pass around to places. In my case the keys are strings.

This is one way:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
let mut map = HashMap::new();
let id = "data".to_string();  // This needs to be a String
let cloned = id.clone();

map.insert(id, 5);

let one = map.get(&cloned);
let two = map.get("data");
println!("{:?}", (one, two));
```

But this requires a clone.

This one worked until Rust 1.2.0:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::string::as_string;

let mut map = HashMap::new();
let data = Rc::new("data".to_string()); // This needs to be a String
let copy = data.clone();
map.insert(data, 5);

let one = map.get(&copy);
let two = map.get(&*as_string("data"));
println!("{:?}", (one, two));
```

How can I accomplish this with Rust 1.2.0?

Ideally I would want to put a key into a HashMap but keep a reference to it, and allow me to access elements in it with `&str` types, with no extra allocating.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/60896

Answer (score 18):

The short answer is that you can't. When you insert something into the `HashMap`, you *transfer ownership*. Doing so invalidates any references that you might have to the key, as the key is *moved* into the memory allocated by the map.

[RFC 1194 (Set Recovery)](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1194-set-recovery.html) proposes a way to get references to the key stored by a `HashSet` (not map). Further information and research was needed to justify supporting this for `HashMap` as well. However, this **still wouldn't help you** as you would need to know the key (or something that can be used to look it up) in order to look it up again. However, you've already put the key in the collection at that point.

Your second solution works because you aren't actually giving ownership of the `String` to the map, you are giving it ownership of a type that models shared ownership via reference counting. The `clone` call simply increments the reference count, and this models how a lot of dynamic languages would solve this problem.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    let data = Rc::new("data".to_string());
    map.insert(data.clone(), 5);

    let v = map.get(&data);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

---

Some unstable features might help you. The most efficient one is [`HashMap::raw_entry_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry_mut):

```
#![feature(hash_raw_entry)]

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    let id = "data";

    let (k, _v) = map
        .raw_entry_mut()
        .from_key(id)
        .or_insert_with(|| (String::from(id), 0));

    println!("{:?}", k);
}
```

A shorter but slightly less efficient solution uses [`Entry::insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.insert)

```
#![feature(entry_insert)]

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    let id = "data";

    let entry = map.entry(String::from(id)).insert(0);
    let k = entry.key();

    println!("{:?}", k);
}
```

See also:

- [How do I use the Entry API with an expensive key that is only constructed if the Entry is Vacant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51542024/155423)

Comment: This solution is great! Although I cannot access data in my map with `&str` types anymore, which is a must. :/

Comment: This RFC  looks like what I need, too bad that HashMaps weren't considered for it.

Comment: Would it be technically difficult or impossible to add a `fn insert_and_get(&mut self, value: T) -> &T` that returns a reference to the newly inserted datum?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I do not think that it would be hard or impossible, no. I've also not tried it myself :-)

Comment: FYI, someone can propose an implementation: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/60142#issuecomment-487416553

Comment: HashSets have an experimental method for `get_or_insert()` that returns a reference to what you inserted: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.get_or_insert

Comment: `Entry::insert` (which never stabilized) has been removed and replaced with [`Entry::insert_entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.insert_entry) (which is also not stabilized yet)