# How can I get a reference to the key and value immediately after inserting into a `HashMap`?

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::*;

fn hook(k: &str, v: &str) {}

fn tt(k: String, v: String) -> Option<String> {
    let mut a: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    match a.entry(k) {
        Occupied(mut occupied) => {
            let old = occupied.insert(v);
            //hook(&k, &old);
            Some(old)
        }
        Vacant(vacant) => {
            let v = vacant.insert(v);
            let k = vacant.key(); // Why doesn't it work?
            //hook(&k, v);
            None
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to call `hook` immediately after a key is inserted into the `HashMap`. It seems I have to use `Entry`. However, I am unable to call `vacant.key()` right after `vacant.insert`.

Comment: It happens because you have already lost your `vacant` object by calling `insert` method and it consumes `Self`. What about getting `key` at first and then inserting the value? And I don't quite understand why do you need it? You already have `k` which is the key.

Comment: Not work either. The original `k` was consumed by `entry`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: You cannot (right now?)

---

The compiler *tells you why it doesn't work*. Don't hesitate to read Rust compiler messages; they aren't scary and a lot of effort has gone into them!

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `vacant`
  --> src/main.rs:16:21
   |
15 |             let v = vacant.insert(v);
   |                     ------ value moved here
16 |             let k = vacant.key();
   |                     ^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `vacant` has type `std::collections::hash_map::VacantEntry<'_, std::string::String, std::string::String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

This is just normal Rust code. [`VacantEntry::insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.VacantEntry.html#method.insert) consumes `self`by value, returning a reference to the inserted value:

```
fn insert(self, value: V) -> &'a mut V
```

There are [over 100 other question/answer pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+use+of+moved+value+is%3Aq) that ask about this error message, so I'll assume you've read enough of them to understand the problem; that's why we answer questions on Stack Overflow after all!

---

So *why* is it this way? That's tougher to answer. When you insert into a `HashMap`, it takes ownership of the key and the value. When you use the `entry` API, there's an intermediate step - you've given ownership of the key to the entry. The entry *also* has a mutable reference to the `HashMap`; a "bookmark" of where the value is.

When the value is missing and then you insert a value, the key is transferred out of the entry and into the `HashMap`. This means that the reference to the key inside the entry would be invalidated. That's why you can't reorder the two lines.

However, thinking about it a bit deeper, the *value* returned from `insert` refers to the underlying `HashMap`, after the value has been inserted. I can't see any reason preventing a function from being added that returns a reference to the key and the value. However, such a function doesn't exist now.

See also [How can I keep a reference to a key after it has been inserted into a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32401857/155423)

---

I'm pretty sure in *this* case you don't need the functionality though.

If you want to call it for the *new* value, just do all of this before the insertion:

```
hook(&k, &v);
a.insert(k, v);
```

If you want to do it only for the old value, doing nothing when there wasn't previously a value, you can:

```
Occupied(mut occupied) => {
    let old = occupied.insert(v);
    hook(occupied.key(), &old);
    Some(old)
}
```

If you want to call the hook with the **old** value if there was one and the **new** value if inserting (which seems inconsistent), you can call it *before* adding, the `hook` function will be none the wiser as the arguments are just references:

```
Vacant(vacant) => {
    hook(vacant.key(), &v);
    let v = vacant.insert(v);
    None
}
```