# How do I use the Entry API with an expensive key that is only constructed if the Entry is Vacant?

Tags: rust, hashmap

Is it possible to use the [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) API to get a value by a `AsRef<str>`, but inserting it with `Into<String>`?

This is the working example:

```rust
use std::collections::hash_map::{Entry, HashMap};

struct Foo;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Map {
    map: HashMap<String, Foo>,
}

impl Map {
    fn get(&self, key: impl AsRef<str>) -> &Foo {
        self.map.get(key.as_ref()).unwrap()
    }

    fn create(&mut self, key: impl Into<String>) -> &mut Foo {
        match self.map.entry(key.into()) {
            Entry::Vacant(entry) => entry.insert(Foo {}),
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }

    fn get_or_create(&mut self, key: impl Into<String>) -> &mut Foo {
        match self.map.entry(key.into()) {
            Entry::Vacant(entry) => entry.insert(Foo {}),
            Entry::Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = Map::default();
    map.get_or_create("bar");
    map.get_or_create("bar");
    assert_eq!(map.map.len(), 1);
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=644a89e615a7503fc87742513b367816)

My problem is that in `get_or_create` a `String` will always be created, incurring unneeded memory allocation, even if it's not needed for an occupied entry. Is it possible to fix this in any way? Maybe in a neat way with [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In nightly Rust, you can use the unstable [`raw_entry_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry_mut) feature that allows this:

> Creates a raw entry builder for the HashMap.
>
> [...]
>
> Raw entries are useful for such exotic situations as:
>
> - Deferring the creation of an owned key until it is known to be required

In stable Rust, you can add the [hashbrown](https://crates.io/crates/hashbrown) crate which has the same API but stable. The hashbrown crate is actually the underlying implementation of the standard library's hashmap.

Example:

```rust
#![feature(hash_raw_entry)]
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Hash, PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
struct NoCopy {
    foo: i32,
}

impl Clone for NoCopy {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        println!("Clone of: {:?}", self);
        Self { foo: self.foo }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let no_copy = NoCopy { foo: 21 };

    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    map.raw_entry_mut()
        .from_key(&no_copy)
        .or_insert_with(|| (no_copy.clone(), 42));

    map.raw_entry_mut()
        .from_key(&no_copy)
        .or_insert_with(|| (no_copy.clone(), 84));

    println!("{:#?}", map);
}
```

Applied to your original example:

```
fn get_or_create<K>(&mut self, key: K) -> &mut Foo
where
    K: AsRef<str> + Into<String>,
{
    self.map
        .raw_entry_mut()
        .from_key(key.as_ref())
        .or_insert_with(|| (key.into(), Foo))
        .1
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You cannot, safely. This is a limitation of the current entry API, and there's no great solution. The anticipated solution is the "raw" entry API. See [Stargateur's answer for an example of using it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921965/155423).

The only stable solution using the Entry API is to always clone the key:

```
map.entry(key.clone()).or_insert(some_value);
```

Outside of the Entry API, you can check if the map contains a value and insert it if not:

```
if !map.contains_key(&key) {
    map.insert(key.clone(), some_value);
}

map.get(&key).expect("This is impossible as we just inserted a value");
```

See also:

- [[Pre-RFC] Abandonning Morals In The Name Of Performance: The Raw Entry API](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-abandonning-morals-in-the-name-of-performance-the-raw-entry-api/7043)
- [WIP: add raw_entry API to HashMap (50821)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/50821)
- [Extend entry API to work on borrowed keys. (1769)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1769)
- [Add HashMap.entry_or_clone() method (1203)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1203)

For non-`entry` based solutions, see:

- [How to avoid temporary allocations when using a complex key for a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36480845/155423)
- [How to implement HashMap with two keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786717/155423)

Comment: I don't see why we couldn't have had `Entry` that keeps a `Cow<'_, K>` instead of `K` (and potentially copies when a vacant entry is inserted). Is there a reason why that approach would not work, or is it just not the one that was chosen and stability expectations preclude such changes?

Comment: @RobertObryk not all types are copyable, for one. At this point, it's certainly the case that it can't be changed due to backwards compatibility concerns.

Answer (score 0):

The [`hashbrown`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown) crate (it's the same implementation that powers std's `HashMap`) provides the [`entry_ref()`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry_ref) API for that:

```rust
use hashbrown::hash_map::{EntryRef, HashMap};

struct Foo;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Map {
    map: HashMap<String, Foo>,
}

impl Map {
    fn get(&self, key: impl AsRef<str>) -> &Foo {
        self.map.get(key.as_ref()).unwrap()
    }

    fn create(&mut self, key: impl AsRef<str>) -> &mut Foo {
        match self.map.entry_ref(key.as_ref()) {
            EntryRef::Vacant(entry) => entry.insert(Foo {}),
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }

    fn get_or_create(&mut self, key: impl AsRef<str>) -> &mut Foo {
        match self.map.entry_ref(key.as_ref()) {
            EntryRef::Vacant(entry) => entry.insert(Foo {}),
            EntryRef::Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
        }
        // Or:
        // self.map.entry_ref(key.as_ref()).or_insert(Foo {})
    }
}
```