# How to look up values in a HashMap<Option<String>, V> without copying?

Tags: rust, hashmap, option-type

I have a `HashMap` with `Option<String>` keys; is it possible to do lookups with a key of type `Option<&str>`? I know I can use a `&str` to lookup in a `HashMap<String, V>` because `str` implements `Borrow<String>`.

Do I have to convert to an owned string just to do a lookup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the Entry API with an expensive key that is only constructed if the Entry is Vacant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542024/how-do-i-use-the-entry-api-with-an-expensive-key-that-is-only-constructed-if-the)

Comment: The Entry api is for optionally adding a key to the map, I am only talking about lookups.

Comment: for the last time duplicate is about answer not question read the answer not the question *- -

Comment: With the raw entry api, the only solution I can think of is to use `map.raw_entry().from_hash(somehow_calculate_a_hash(key), |k| k.as_ref() == key)`.

Comment: no where in the thread I link to you there is write `from_hash()`. I can't read for you.

Comment: Nowhere in that thread is a direct answer to my question. I assumed that you meant that I should use the raw_entry API as is suggested in the accepted answer for that question. If that is not what you meant, then what did you mean?

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=82f51e3bf8a0f73a0636436b8005734c, doesn't seem to be possible with Option, anyway have an Option as key in a Hashmap don't make sense

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly less efficient, but you could use `Cow` here. It avoids the problem with the `Borrow` trait by instead having a single type that can represent either a reference or an owned value, like so:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::<Option<Cow<'static, str>>, i32>::new();
    map.insert(None, 5);
    map.insert(Some(Cow::Borrowed("hello")), 10);
    map.insert(Some(Cow::Borrowed("world")), 15);
    
    // works with None and constant string slices...
    assert_eq!(map.get(&None), Some(&5));
    assert_eq!(map.get(&Some(Cow::Borrowed("hello"))), Some(&10));
    
    // ...and also works with heap-allocated strings, without copies
    let stack = String::from("world");
    assert_eq!(map.get(&Some(Cow::Borrowed(&stack))), Some(&15));
}
```